# krb5.conf file ignored by tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to setup kerberos/spnego authentication using tomcat. I added a krb5.conf file under the tomcat directory and in SpnegoFilterConfig the value is read and java.security.krb5.conf is set , however it seems not to be taken in consideration. No matter if the file is there or not i get the same result.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)
```

If i put the jce security files in lib/security i get

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
```

However this is happening no matter if i have the krb5.conf or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you replaced your security policy files with the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for Java?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: yes if i do so i get "Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)"

Comment: If i try the HelloKDC example from spnego website and play around with the krb5.conf file i get the expected error(s) (for example if i set an encryption type not supported by my kdc), but on tomcat i can just detele krb5.conf file or put anything in it and still get the errors from above